# How to install xamarin studio?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin-studio

I just download xamarin through this link

https://www.xamarin.com/download with (I already have Visual Studio installed) NO

but it seems only installed visual studio for me, as i see some tutorial on youtube there is a xamarin studio.

https://youtu.be/6Jx7ZNZL9dk?list=PLCuRg51-gw5VqYchUekCqxUS9hEZkDf6l&t=168

But it seems xamarin studio is not installed for my computer, anyone know where is xamarin studio and how to install it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the Xamarin FAQ page:

> Do you still offer Xamarin Studio on Windows?
>
> Xamarin Studio is no longer included with our Windows installer. We
>   encourage Windows developers to move to Visual Studio.

https://www.xamarin.com/faq#xpq6